# Getting the last revision of several files to resolve merge conflicts

Tags: svn, merge

On my company, we have recently created a new version of an application that is in production. As you may guess, its development was composed by multiple iterations and were made multiple commits regarding the same file.

In order to help the merging process (I'm using the subclipse plugin) I would to know if is possible to select the last revision of a given file, for avoiding intermediate merges once they are "blocking" the merging process.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using [svnmerge](http://www.orcaware.com/svn/wiki/Svnmerge.py); it automates a lot of the confusing aspects of merging in subversion.

With regards to your specific question, it might help if you provide an example of your project structure in subversion and whether people have been working on separate branches. I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'select the last revision of a file' - you can merge whatever individual revisions you like, but they won't always merge cleanly if they rely on earlier changes.